# 2 pdfs look same on XP, different on Win7

Tags: pdf

I have 2 pdf files.

I compared them with WinMerge, BeyondCompare, and even compared their checksums. They are exactly the same to me in every way.

If I open them with Adobe Reader in Xp, and compare them with my bare eyes, they look the same.

But!!! If I open them with Adobe Reader in Win7, and compare them with my bare eyes, they look very different!(particularly border width).

Here are the 2 pdf files I'm talking about:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gdqyzrcqj2qgqwc/N6GtxktDeg
```

And here is a screenshot of the 2 files. The one on the right side has thicker border if you look carefully. Remember, they have the same checksum.[image]

I would really appreciate it if any clues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Reader are you using on each system?

Comment: Try a different pdf reader.  I wonder if acrobat is not remembering some sort of per document view settings, like zoom level or something.

Comment: I tried other pdf reader(PDFXCview) which shows the 2 files are same. I'm using abode reader X 10.1.4. Problem is, I believe the 2 files are same in every bit, yet they look different on the same Adobe reader, how is that even possible?

Comment: Sounds like a font substitution (the font is not available one one of the machines)

Comment: screenshot is taken in Win7. if it's font substitution, it should happen on both files. That doesn't explain why they look different. :(

Comment: What if you scale both documents to 100%? Are they still different? The files are identical, look the same on OS X as well, I guess for some reason Adobe Reader decided to use a different drawing/interpolation algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Cooper said, this could be something related to the version of Adobe you are using. If you are still unsure, use MD5 ALGORITHM to generate hash for the files and compare them WITH BARE EYES :p
Hash values don't lie. Even if a single character is different, the entire hash will change. Google AVALANCE EFFECT to know more.
`If hashes are same, files are same. Forget the looks as being something related to version`

Comment: I used free commander to generate checksums of the 2 files. And the checksums matched. By that I assume the 2 files are same in every bit, and yet they look different in the same program, how is that possible?

Comment: It maybe because Adobe guys changed the interface to look different. Are you using the same magnification level in both the programs? That could cause the margins to look wide/narrow. If you look at various versions of Adobe, you'll find that UI is quite different. So rest assured, files are the same =) `Hash values don't lie`

Comment: they are at the same magnification level. It is not the UI that's different, it is the contents that's different. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: So you're saying if file 1 says WHITE file 2 says BLACK? Plus it'll be great to post screenshots using printscreen. It's easier than downloading plus your data will be safe =) just upload the image you want use community to see

Comment: The files are identical. While there can be hash collisions in carefully crafted files, both files have the same checksums in both `md5sum` and `sha1sum`.

Comment: I have compared them byte by byte using Java. they are identical in every byte.

Comment: Try using `Nitro PDF`. That's another PDF reader